# Emacs query-replace-regexp multiline

Tags: regex, emacs

How do you do a query-replace-regexp in Emacs that will match across multiple lines?

as a trivial example I'd want `<p>\(.*?\)</p>` to match

```
<p>foo
bar
</p>
```

Comment: I assume you saw emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp

Comment: yeah i saw that but couldn't get it to work using query-replace-regexp. still trying though using re-builder to test it...hopefully i'll figure it out soon

Comment: The example is very bad, because parsing HTML with regular expressions is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Obviously there's a difference between trying to parse, eg de-serialize or scrape HTML with regex and using it to save time and typing while editing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try character classes.  As long as you're using only ASCII character set, you can use `[[:ascii:]]` instead of the dot.  Using the longer `[[:ascii:][:nonascii:]]` ought to work for everything.

Comment: And if you're not using just ASCII?

Comment: [[:ascii:][:nonascii:]]* gives me stack overflow

Comment: @helcim you should make it non-greedy by adding a `?` at the end.

Comment: “Search failed with status 0: grep: Invalid character class name“

Answer (score 25):

```
M-x re-builder
```

is your friend.  And it led me to this regular expression:

```
"<p>\\(.\\|\n\\)*</p>"
```

which is the string version of

```
<p>\(.\|^J\)*</p>         ;# where you enter ^J by C-q C-j
```

And that works for me when I do re-search-forward, but not when I do `'query-replace-regexp`.  Unsure why...

Now, when doing a `'re-search-forward` (aka `C-u C-s`), you can type `M-%` which will prompt you for a replacement (as of Emacs 22).  So, you can use that to do your search and replace with the above regexp.

Note, the above regexp will match until the *last* `</p>` found in the buffer, which is probably not what you want, so use re-builder to build a regexp that comes closer to what you want.  Obviously regular expressions can't count parenthesis, so you're on your own for that - depends on how robust a solution you want.

Comment: Are there info files for re-builder?  I'm curious about how to use it.

Comment: Not that I can find.  The Emacs Wiki doesn't have much on it either.  But it's pretty self-explanatory (isn't all of Emacs :).  After entering `re-builder`, type `C-c C-h` and you'll get a listing of bindings including those that apply to `re-builder` which all begin with `C-c`.

Comment: Yah, I got that far.  Was just looking for something a bit more in depth.  Thanks!

Comment: “Search failed with status 0: grep: Unmatched ( or \\(“